# confused regarding AWS lambda function execution limits

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I was check AWS Lambda FAQs regarding how long an AWS Lambda function can execute, but found different information on the following URLs.

1. https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/

   > Q: How long can an AWS Lambda function execute?
   >
   > A: AWS Lambda functions can be configured to run up to 15 minutes per execution. You can set the timeout to any value between 1 second and 15 minutes.
2. https://www.amazonaws.cn/en/lambda/faqs/

   > Q: How long can an AWS Lambda function execute?
   >
   > A: All calls made to AWS Lambda must complete execution within 300 seconds. The default timeout is 3 seconds, but you can set the timeout to any value between 1 and 300 seconds.

can anyone help me to find out which one is correct?

Answer (score 4):

On October 10, 2018 the execution time limit for AWS Lambda functions was **increased from 5 minutes to 15 minutes**.

Therefore, you will still see many references to the old 5 minute limit.

See: [AWS Lambda enables functions that can run up to 15 minutes](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/aws-lambda-supports-functions-that-can-run-up-to-15-minutes/)